# IPIP Tunneling for EC2 instances in different regions

Tags: amazon-ec2, tunneling

According to this [web page](http://wiki.virtastic.com/display/howto/Tunnels), it seems IPIP Tunneling should work in EC2 instances. But I'm not sure whether it also works for instances in difference regions.

Did anyone have experienced it before? How can I configure IPIP to make it work for instances in different regions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course IP tunnels can be created between any two endpoints that can talk to each other. EC2 instances have two IP addresses, an internal 10-dot address that is only routable inside the availability region, and a hard IP that is routable from anywhere. In order to establish a tunnel or any other connectivity between instances in different regions you will need to use the later address.

Note: you will incur bandwidth charges for data between instances in different regions that would be avoided if the instances were in the same data center.

Comment: At last, I gave up the idea somehow. But this approach sounds workable.